# How to change LaTeXilas standard dictionary

Tags: dictionary

I'm using LaTeXila as tex environment and whenever I open a tex file, I have to switch the dictionary for spell checking purposes to en_GB (default dictionary in LaTeXila is de_DE and I'm using the german language on my ubuntu system). Unfortunately, I didn't find a possibility in LaTeXila to change the standard dictionary. I guess that LaTeXila is looking for the default dictionary of the user. Is there a possibility to set the default dictionary to en_GB?

Answer (score 2):

It's been awhile this question was asked but I though the answer would help others.

If you need to change the dictionary simply enable spell check ( `Edit -> Spell Check` ) and right click your document. There's Language selection in context menu which allows you to change current dictionary. This works in version 2.4.0.

Answer (score 0):

While you can get some really good answers about LaTex here at AU, your question is application specific. [Try asking the same question here at the TEX Q&A](https://tex.stackexchange.com/?as=1) . You may get lucky